# Swift 2 Function enforcing Class and Protocol adherence, Generic parameter could not be inferred

Tags: swift, swift2

I have the following code to let me switch away from any view controller to any other one, and the parameter needs to be an `NSViewController` that conforms to the `Delegatable` protocol.

When I call the function on line 3, I get `Generic parameter 'C' could not be inferred`.

```
func foo() {
    var viewController = CustomViewController()
    showViewForController(&viewController)
}

private func showViewForController<C:NSViewController where C:Delegatable>(inout viewController: C) -> Void {
    currentVC?.removeFromParentViewController()
    currentVC?.view.removeFromSuperview()

    viewController.delegate = self
    addChildViewController(viewController)
    self.view.addSubview(viewController.view)
    currentVC = viewController
}
```

Comment: Is your CustomViewController class Delegatable?

Comment: Also, you don't have to pass it as `inout`.

Comment: Also you may have to make your `Delegatable` protocol class bound (`:class`), as Swift sometimes has trouble inferring whether a given generic is a reference type (which may have been why you've tried to use `inout` here).

Comment: @WillM. Yes, that was it, thanks!  If you want to make that an answer I'll accept.  New to XCode, I haven't gotten used to errors in pseudocode being caused by other files...

Comment: @originaluser2 the compiler is complaining that I'm assigning a property (.delegate) if I don't use the `inout`

Comment: @jake That's what I was talking about. If you make the `Delegatabe` protocol class bound, it'll treat your generic parameter as a reference type and therefore dismiss the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CustomViewController doesn't conform to Delegatable, which would give that compiler error when trying to pass it in to your function. The error message isn't exactly helpful though.